# create a table in an outlook message using access vba

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I am using Access to create outlook messages. I need to create a table that i will populate with text strings. What I need to start with is how to create a simple table with  one column two rows that is not folder or html based? The first row will say "I am a Heading" and the second row will say "I am a row". Thanks

Comment: Without HTML, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, your right started working with html and css.  On to the next issue on my list, moving repetitive code from different forms into a stand alone or class module, bbut that for anther day.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body (create a table using the Word object model).

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.